# Someone PLEASE help me get rid of my startup pin. I've done everything and I'm at wits end with this

Tags: twrp, encryption, rom

I own an axon 7 with TWRP and I flash noms pretty regularly. recently I installed a new rom and accidentally ticked the "secure start up pin" feature or whatever (this also created a pin on TWRP for some reason. but with that I noticed it took my device almost twice as long to boot it seemed so I disabled it in the settings, but that did nothing.

I've wiped system, data, cache, Dalvik, everything and NOTHING will get rid of the pin. I've gone into the file manager in TWRP, DELETED THE KEY FILES, AND THEN WIPED AND FLASHED AND IT STILL HAD THE DAMN PIN on startup.

Please someone help me. if this is related to encryption I'd also like to learn how to disable that as well.

thank's in advance for your help, I know you don't have to give it :)

Answer (score 0):

It's `/data` encryption. You must format your whole `/data` partition to decrypt it. Backup **everything** first, your photos, musics, etc. will be gone.

**YOU WILL LOSE ALL YOUR DATA, INCLUDING INTERNAL STORAGE IF YOU PROCEED. THIS CANNOT BE UNDONE**

Comment: I wiped system, data, internal storage, dalvik, and cache and nothing will make the startup pin go away or disable encryption. I also updated twrp with the AXON 7 TOOLKIT and in doing that the program disabled dm-verity AND forced encryption. reflashed new rom and kernel and the same pin is present.

Comment: Hey, "Wipe" is not the right operation. You should find a button named ***Format Data***.